# performance problem with WebKit which gets 50.000 POIs via webservice

Tags: iphone, web-services, xcode, json, webkit

I've got a lot of POIs (compare MKAnnotation Protocol) in a backend on a webserver. I don't want to have a complete dump of all those in an iPhone database since normally you only need the POIs around your area. So my idea was a webservice which gets the actual shown region as paramters and gives back all relevant POIs. So far so good.
BUT also totally crap. Using your finger to swipe left-right-left-right would result in a zillion webrequests. Using a two second delay (do the request after 2 seconds) would result in a bad performance (who wants to wait for such a long time?).
So, **"caching"** is the word of the day. Does anybody now, if there are allready best practise or even pattern for this case? Otherwise here are my two ideas:
1. split the world-map into tiles (perhaps 1 km²). It is possible to identify those tiles by an id. So it would be possible to save in a local database if this tile is allready downloaded (so the POIs would be in the local POI-Database) or not. After a week or so, the entry for this tile would be deleted automatically to refresh the cache.
2. All POIs are cached. If a new region is shown, after two seconds, a request ist sent to the Webservice

What do you think about it? Is there a Datastructure which makes it possible to easily save areas which are not a square (but a set union of squares)?
I would love to hear ideas to this topic,
darth

Answer (score 0):

You could consider only sending a request after the touchesEnded-event. This is how many applications's tableViewCells are working. (for example Twitter loads the avatar after you released your finger from the screen.)